# Trigger to update Account on updating contact

Tags: trigger, custom-field, account, after-trigger

Can someone please tell why below sample code is not working

```
Trigger UpdateParent on contact (After Update){

    List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();

       for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
         if( c.limpus__c == 'Check'){  
           acc = [select id,name,active__c from account where id =: c.accountid];
           for(Account a: acc){
               a.active__c = 'No';
               acc.add(a);
           }
        }
      }
      Update acc;
   }
```

Comment: It looks like you've received some solid answers, but please remember that your questions should always include a clear, detailed statement of the problem. "Not working" does not fit our format and often prevents the community from helping you effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using SOQL statements in side for loop is very bad practice, so try to avoid it. here is example of working code.

```
Trigger UpdateParent on contact (After Update){

//List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
  set<Id> sAccId = new set<Id>();

   for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
     if( c.limpus__c == 'Check'){
            sAccId.add(con.AccountId);
     }
  }
 List<Account> acclst = [select id,name,active__c from account where id IN: sAccId];
 for(Account acc: acclst){
        a.active__c = 'No';
 }
 if(acclst.size() > 0){
    update acclst;
}
```

}

Comment: We don't need to query account right?

Comment: Thank you @sdandamud1. Also could you please help me out with some weblinks for collections and  Map. I will be really grateful to you.

Comment: @KathyM Welcome to SFSE. Please take our [tour] and read [ask]. Any further questions that you have need to be in a separate question post.

Comment: @KathyM go through this link for more explanation for MAP,LIST,SET http://womencodeheroes.com/2015/01/cooking-with-code-amuse-bouche-of-apex-collections-lists-sets-and-maps/

Comment: @rahulgawale yes for this Question don't need a query, but if need more checks on Account list better to have query the list of accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You have written a SOQL query in a for loop, which you should never write in a loop.

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) is why.

You can rewrite it as below.

```
Trigger UpdateParent on contact (After Update){
    List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();

    Set<id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
        if( c.limpus__c == 'Check'){  
           accountIdSet.add(c.accountid);
        }
    }

    accountIdSet.remove(null);

    Account[] accountstoUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Id accId:accountIdSet ){
        accountstoUpdate.add(new Account(id = accId, active__c = 'No'))
    }
    Update accountstoUpdate;
}
```